# Why do people use this G as a favicon?

Tags: image, web, blogger, favicon, ico

I have seen many websites, such as http://www.technoblip.com, using this image as their `favicon.ico`. It is like a white capital *G* in a black circle as shown in the image.[image: G favicon]

What is this from? Is there any special meaning of this favicon?

Comment: Which websites use this image?

Comment: Not only one i have seen this in many sites just tell me is this G favicon having some hidden MEANING

Comment: _Which_ websites? Knowing which ones could help shed light on the meaning.

Comment: [www.technoblip.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's the standard favicon/logo from [Genesis Framework](http://www.studiopress.com/features), a framework for WordPress sites and used on the site you mentioned in your comments. It can be found on that site at http://www.technoblip.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/images/favicon.ico:

[image: Genesis Framework "G" favicon image]

Not really a hidden meaning or anything.

Comment: The image in the question looks waaay more sinister! :-)